# How to plot different data in parallel (in continuation of the previous one)

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some energy 24 hour consumption data of many days.
Plotting a specific day gives me vertical axis of consumption and horizontal axis of time.
I would like to plot for lets say 1 year. 
If I use "hold on/off" command, it plots all days together on top of each other.
How can i plot in a way that for the second day, the plots goes to the continue of the first plot (horizontal axis extends automatically)? So, when I have the complete plot, it shows 365 days of energy consumption based on hour. It's like the horizontal axis is repeating while the vertical axis is updating. I'm talking about MATLAB.

[image: (http://i59.tinypic.com/1qq3uv.jpg )]

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `hold on` and plot each day separately (if I understand your question properly, this is what you want, separate plotting). Simply make sure your x-axis values are correct. So e.g. if you have one measurement value per hour, the plot day 1:

```
plot(1:24,valDay1,'k-')
```

then for day 2:

```
plot(25:48,valDay2,'r-')
```

etc. This will line things up correctly. Also, consider using a `datetime` as x axis values

Answer (score 0):

So, I found my solution which is very simple. I don't know how it didn't occur earlier.
I just had to use ";" and that's it.
Like this:

DAY=[day1;day2;day3]

plot(DAY)